# Many To Many Database with EF Core5 Error

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Plaase help!!!: I created 2 entities and added DbSets to ApplicationDbContext.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Adi { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<Firma> Firmalar {get; set;}
}

public class Firma
{
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

onPost Method I want to add List to ApplicationUser Table with relation. I can see ApplicationUserFirma table has automatically created

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddFirmaToUser(UserFirmaVM vm, ServisHaritasi.DataService.Models.Firma firma)
{
    var dbuser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(vm.ApplicationUser.Id);
    var dbfirma = await _db.Firmalar.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == firma.Id);

    if (dbuser != null && dbfirma != null)
    {
        dbuser.Firmalar.Add(dbfirma); **///I GET EXCEPTION HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**
        
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        return RedirectToPage("./Duzenle", new {id = dbuser.Id});
    }
    return Page();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lflst.jpg)
I assure  you there is no null for dbuser and dbfirma. they are coming normally on debug.
Plase help!!!

Stack trace is here:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
webUI.Pages.Users.DuzenleModel.OnPostAddFirmaToUser(UserFirmaVM vm, Firma firma) in Duzenle.cshtml.cs
+
                dbuser.Firmalar.Add(dbfirma);
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert<T>(object taskAsObject)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the issue is. Could you please clarify your problem? If there is any exception thrown, please post the error message.

Comment: on exception line.. it gives NullRefeerence Exception. But there is nothing null I suppose!

Comment: I can tell the `Firmalar` in `dbuser` is null.

Comment: I know it is null so I am adding it:)

Comment: post the exact error and stack trace please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use include Firma for ApplicationUser:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddFirmaToUser(UserFirmaVM vm, ServisHaritasi.DataService.Models.Firma firma)
{
 
     var dbuser = await _db.Set<ApplicationUser>()
                          .Include(i=>i.Firmalar)
                          .Where(m => m.Id == vm.ApplicationUser.Id)
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var dbfirma = await _db.Firmalar.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == firma.Id);

    if (dbuser != null && dbfirma != null)
    {
        if(dbuser.Firmalar==null) dbuser.Firmalar= new List<Firmalar>();
        dbuser.Firmalar.Add(dbfirma); 
        
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        return RedirectToPage("./Duzenle", new {id = dbuser.Id});
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: @N.OZERSENOL Welcome to the community. If this answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetching the user as -

```
var dbuser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(vm.ApplicationUser.Id);
```

the related `Firmalar` list is not included. So it remains null. Then You are trying to add to this null list -

```
dbuser.Firmalar.Add(dbfirma);
```

That's where the issue is.

Try to fetch the user including the `Firmalar` list, like -

```
var dbuser = await _db.ApplicationUser
                .Include(p=> p.Firmalar)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p=> p.Id == vm.ApplicationUser.Id);
```

That should solve the issue.